# Why is Rails runner not returning a result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runner

I am having problems with the Rails runner. When I try to use if, even by command line, it does nothing! it doesn't show error messages, nor results from actions.

For example, if I try

```
rails runner Credit.count
```

having defined the model `Credit`, and the method count as

```
Credit.first.update_attribute(:estado, "En proceso")
```

or even simpler tasks, the runner does nothing!

I've tried saying that the environment is development, but nothing works. Does anyone has any insights? Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I am watching the database, that's the problem, there is no update. I changed the value of the column "estado" for the first element to something other than "En proceso", however, no matter how many times I use the runner, the db doesn't show any change at all.

Comment: if you try other rails console command (like `rails console`), all is fine?

Comment: Try to do this: rails runner "puts Credit.count"

Comment: rails console works. Puts doesn't print anything in console.

Answer (score 2):

> **rails runner**: runner runs Ruby code in the context of Rails non-interactively

**update_attribute** : it only return true or false, if you want to output the result, you can use "puts" or "p".

For example,

```
$ rails r "User.first" #no output, even it will return a user object
$ rails r "puts User.first" # you can use "puts" get the output
#<User:0x007f8a2c76e608>
```

Comment: That works as well. Hoever, putting the same code on the model Credit and calling it using rails r does not.

Answer (score 0):

if you just written `Credit.first.update_attribute(:estado, "En proceso")` in console, you shouldn't have results, but you could see result in DB, for checking if `update_attribute` really update it you could write as `update_attribute!` also you could just write:

`p Credit.first.update_attribute(:estado, "En proceso")` which should print `true` or `false` to console

Comment: The thing is, the db is not being updated, there is no change in the table I am updating.

Comment: even if you write something like `p 'hello world'` you don't have it in console?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am an idiot.

First, I had to change the name of the method, calling Credit.count calls the default count method, so I changed it to myMethod.

After that, I was able to use puts function and update the database easily :)